# Give up bucket-owner read permission, and grant to another user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to create a file in your own bucket that only another user can read? Ideally the bucket owner can still delete it, but cannot modify the policy after giving up permissions. This is for a use case where privacy is important.

The idea is, people submit a job that is run (using our AWS account) on EC2, and their input and output data should be considered private. The input data is pulled directly into the instance and no one has access to the EC2 instance while it runs. However, after the job is complete, it would be convenient to store the output data on S3 for a while so the users can download parts of it at their discretion. Ideally the user doesn't have to do anything that requires significant knowledge of AWS/S3. At most they could provide an account ID.

The goal is that I can create a policy that guarantees once the file is uploaded, only the user can read it. The user should have no other privileges and my only privilege should be deleting the output data.

Comment: If you deny bucket policy modifications to its owner, who would be able to modify it then later on?

Comment: Also the bucket owner is the account, so you want to block the account's root to modify the policy?

Comment: Can you tell us about your actual use-case? That is, tell us _what_ you'd like to accomplish rather than _how?_ We might be able to recommend a better approach.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein alright I updated my question with more details

Comment: How are you authenticating/identifying your users? Do they login to a back-end app? Or are you expecting them to have their own AWS Account? Or are they IAM Users within _your_ AWS Account?

Comment: We are assuming they have their own separate account, and we don't want to put too much work into a complex backend. It would be even more convenient if we could assume they have no account at all and just give them a download link (somehow). The fundamental issue is really just being able to host files and guarantee we can't read them, and that they are not publicly discoverable.